# Trying to generate some activity to generate archivelogs

Tags: database, oracle

I am testing some backup utility working with Oracle DB 19c where Im trying to generate some archive logs so that it is able to be deleted after a certain size.

Is there some way to quickly generate redo logs via artificially creating load so that they are pushed to archivelogs?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  Anything you do generates redo so you could just write a loop that loads a table with 1000 rows, deletes those rows, loads them again, etc. until you've generated however much redo you'd like.  Is that what you're looking for?  Or is there some nuance (i.e. you want to generate more load than you could with a single thread, looking for a tool that can spawn a bunch of different threads, etc)?

Comment: Archive logs should be deleted after they are backed up so your DB could be recovered if need be. It should not be deleted based on size. Check the RMAN command delete expired and test your recovery strategy very well

Comment: Yep I suppose generating a script that constantly creates and deletes rows is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to generate redo would be the following

- Be sure to have the tablespace with `logging` mode or the table created with the `logging` option. If the tablespace was created without specifying any logging mode, the default mode is logging. Same applied for the table.
- To avoid issues with storage, just truncate the table in each main loop.
- Be sure that you have enough space for at least one loop iteration, thereby you won't get any error.

In the example below, we put the tablespace in `force logging` mode , although it is not necessary. Then I create a test table with just three fields, but you can use as many as you want, just remember you need storage for at least one iteration.

I use `dbms_random` to generate random string values.

Example

```
alter tablespace users force logging; -- if the tablespace has nologging 

create table x ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(50), c3 varchar2(50) ) logging tablespace users ; -- table in logging mode 

declare
num_loops pls_integer := 10; -- use as many iterations as you want. 
begin
for r in 1..num_loops
loop
    for h in 1 .. 100000 -- I just define 100k for main loop to avoid undo issues
    loop
        insert into x values ( h , dbms_random.string('X',50), dbms_random.string('X',50) ) ;
    end loop;
    commit;
    execute immediate ' truncate table x reuse storage ' ;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: thanks, this was what I was looking for! really appreciated.

Comment: @user3462083, the best way to say thank you in SO is to accept the answer.